# How to search records Based on date format in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field createdDate of type date, which are of two formats `yyyy/mm/dd` and `yyyy/MM/dd` timezone format. How can I search records which are of `yyyy/mm/dd` format.

Comment: you mean to search records through an ES query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the date format when you write the query.

eg:

```
"range": {
                            "documentdate": {
                                "gte": "2016-11-24T00:00:00+00:00",

                                "format": "date_time_no_millis"
                            }
                        }
```